# @Async, Future, AsyncResult; What methods are there of "awaiting" completion of the Async functions

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous

Context: I'm very new to Spring and have never used @Async before.  I've been directed to duplicate parts of code based off of sample code sent to me in an email.

If I were going to do this, the only way I can tell of based on documentation and guides for @async is to use Future.isDone() and maybe have a list that I can remove nodes from when they are "done" and continuing once the list is empty.

What I would like to know is if there are other ways of knowing when 'future' is done?

No where in the sample code given to me is there a future.isDone() line.

They simply call another function after the async requests have been made, which uses a for loop as

```
for (Entry<AClass, Future<String>> a : b.entrySet()) {
```

Is there some sort of magic iterator voodoo going on here with the "foreach", or is maybe my sample code someone been given to me incomplete, or is there something else going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are getting confused on `future.isDone()` method

**isDone** It will just return either true or false

> Returns true if completed in any fashion: normally, exceptionally, or via cancellation.

**And to perform actions on Future object you don't need to call `future.isDone()` and find out whether task is completed or not**

**public T get()
      throws InterruptedException,
             ExecutionException**  (you should see this method)

> Waits if necessary for this future to complete, and then returns its result.
>
> Throws:
>
> CancellationException - if this future was cancelled
>
> ExecutionException - if this future completed exceptionally
>
> InterruptedException - if the current thread was interrupted while waiting